# Catching zoom event on Safari mobile (iPad)

Tags: javascript, ipad, extjs, mobile-safari, zooming

I need to make our ExtJs powered web application work in mobile Safari on the iPad.

Most things are working, but the "zoom" event on the ipad messes up the layouts, I think I just need to fire a resize on the ExtJS viewport but I don't know how to catch the zoom on the ipad in safari, is it even possible?

**Note:**
I know that ExtJs is not recommended for tablet PC's, and at some point in the future I'm hoping to look into building an alternative UI based around Secha Touch or similar, but for now I need to have it functional. You know what it's like :)

Answer (score 1):

I have been dealing with a similar situation while using EXT-GWT. I have not had much luck, but see if this post helps you: http://adactio.com/journal/4470/

Comment: Cheers, I'm actually messing about with this at the moment - a related issue is that I might need to enable double-click (as an alternative to right-click), so the only way to do that is to disable user-zooming - which would remove this issue